# Liouville's theorem for conformal mappings: differentiable functions?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, conformal-geometry

Apparently [Liouville's theorem for conformal mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) holds for functions in $W^{1,n}$. Am I to understand that potentially, there are everywhere differentiable functions to which it doesn't apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any conformal differentiable map $f \colon \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is automatically $W_\text{loc}^{1,n}$: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351088/regularity-of-conformal-maps